# How to Convert a Month from INT to VARCHAR when grouping the date by MONTH

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, date-conversion, sql-date-functions

I need to summarize number of interviews for each month for all the years in a readable way.

```
SELECT month(i.Date) AS Month, Year(i.Date) AS Year, Count(i.Id) AS' Number of Interviews'
FROM Interviews i
GROUP BY month(i.Date), year(i.Date)
ORDER BY year(i.Date) DESC, month(Date) ASC
```

I want the query to return Month as VARCHAR like 'January' instead of default INT from 'month' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **MySql** it would be:

```
SELECT 
  monthname(i.Date) AS Month, 
  Year(i.Date) AS Year, 
  Count(i.Id) AS `Number of Interviews`
FROM Interviews i
GROUP BY month(i.Date), monthname(i.Date), year(i.Date)
ORDER BY year(i.Date) DESC, month(i.Date) ASC
```

For **SQL Server**:

```
SELECT 
  datename(month, i.date) AS Month, 
  Year(i.Date) AS Year, 
  Count(i.Id) AS [Number of Interviews]
FROM Interviews i
GROUP BY month(i.Date), datename(month, i.date), year(i.Date)
ORDER BY year(i.Date) DESC, month(i.Date) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution, that works for most DBMS is a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT CASE month(i.date)
         WHEN 1 THEN
           'January'
         ...
         WHEN 12 THEN
           'December'
       END month,
       year(i.date) year,
       count(i.id) number_of_interviews
       FROM interviews i
       GROUP BY month(i.date),
                year(i.date)
       ORDER BY year(i.date) DESC,
                month(i.date) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(1), format(dateColumn, 'yyyy-MM')
FROM tableName
GROUP BY format(dateColumn, 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY 2
```